# Parachain RPC errors since Polkadot 0.9.36 client upgrade

Tags: rpc, websocket, https

Astar uplifted to Polkadot 0.9.36 in [v4.47.1](https://github.com/AstarNetwork/Astar/releases/tag/v4.47.1)
Client upgrade introduces 2 new errors on RPC nodes, both WS and HTTP.

- HTTP: lots of these errors - seems high impact

```
HTTP serve connection failed hyper::Error(Shutdown, Os { code: 107, kind: NotConnected, message: "Transport endpoint is not connected" })
```

- WS: few of these errors - seems just informative of a connection terminated on client side

```
    WS transport error: i/o error: Connection reset by peer (os error 104); terminate connection: 11
```

Load balancer shows a massive increase of 4xx errors on backend side since nodes upgrade.

[image]

Any idea what this may be due to, especially on the HTTP interface?

Comment: This issue may be related: https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/issues/6461

Comment: Unfortunately no, this issue is pointing a bad termination of WS connection. We also have this message on WS endpoints but it is not a big deal, most probably the client that ends connection on its side.
My errors are related to HTTP endpoint and we have a lot of them.

Comment: I have edited the description to make difference of both errors clear

Answer (score 0):

> HTTP serve connection failed hyper::Error(Shutdown, Os { code: 107,
> kind: NotConnected, message: "Transport endpoint is not connected" })

That could actually happen on regular HTTP requests or during the initial WebSocket handshake (HTTP upgrade request to WebSocket).

The error itself occurs when reading looks like a TLS/SSL error, are you sure that you have configured TLS/SSL on the server correctly?

Otherwise, please open another issue how to reproduce this.

> WS transport error: i/o error: Connection reset by peer (os error
> 104); terminate connection: 11

These are harmless and will be downgraded to debug in the next release, so just ignore them it's something else.

Comment: Thanks, the thing is nothing has been changed on our side, the error only appears when switching from an older version to Astar v4.47.1 which contains Polkadot v0.9.36 uplift.
I can't help but think this is coming from this one much probably.
https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/12663

Comment: Yes, it does but this is not necessarily an issue in the server for instance it could be client the dropped the socket prematurely or something. So again, if you find a way to reproduce it would help and create an issue in substrate or jsonrpsee. Thus, the error is really that hyper couldn't upgrade the socket to a service....